# Simulation of Gamma process (distribution of increments)

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, probability, simulations

The gamma process is a Levy process $X$, where $X_t$ has gamma distribution with parameters $at,b>0$ and density
$$f\left(x\right)=\frac{b^{at}}{\Gamma\left(at\right)}x^{at-1}e^{-bx}$$

I want to simulate gamma process by increments but what is the distribution of $X_t - X_s$? Of course gamma but with what parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Lévy process is defined as (Lévy process and Stochastic Calculus, David Applebaum):

> Suppose that we are given a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$. A Lévy process $X = (X (t), t \geq 0)$ taking values in $\mathbb{R}^d$ is essentially a
> stochastic process having stationary and independent increments; we
> always assume that $X (0) = 0$ with probability 1. So:
>
> - each $X (t) : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^d$;
> - given any selection of distinct time-points $0 \leq t_1 < t_2 < \ldots < t_n$, the
>   random vectors $X(t_1), X(t_2) − X(t_1), X(t_3) − X(t_2), \ldots, X (t_n) − X(t_{n−1})$
>   are all independent;
> - given any two distinct times $0 \leq s < t < \infty$, the probability distribution of
>   $X(t) − X(s)$ coincides with that of $X(t − s)$.

The [Gamma distribution is scale invariant under summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution#Summation), i.e.
$$\sum_{i=1}^N X_i = \mathrm{Gamma}\left(\sum_{i=1}^N k_i, \theta\right)$$
so thanks to the third property $X_t - X_s$ has parameters $a (t - s), b$.